# How to prevent multiple even firings with recursive Backbone.js views?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have an application with a nested list I am trying to manage with backbone. there is a view for each individual `<li>` element, but each list element has it's own nested `<ul>` tag, which has its own view instantiated. here is an example:

**HTML**

```
<ul class='elements'>
  <li class='element'>
     <div>
       <a class='edit-element'>Edit</a>
     </div>
     <ul class='elements'>
       <li class='element'>
         <div>
           <a class='edit-element'>Edit</a>
         </div>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
element_view = Backbone.view.extend({
  events: {
    'click .edit-element' : 'edit_element'
  },
  edit_element : function(event) {
    //code to handle editing of an element
  } 
});
```

The issue is that if I click on a child element, both views will fire there edit_element event, which is problematic for several reasons. How can I structure this so that when I click a link in a child `<li>`, it fires for that `<li>`, and not any `<li>`s that contain it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backbone's event handlers are just plain old jQuery event handlers so you can stop propagation in the usual ways using [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
edit_element: function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
    //...
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Yb8rg/1/

Or by returning `false`:

```
edit_element: function(event) {
    //...
    return false;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/QvaGM/1/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what "mu is too short" already said, I can think of three ways to solve this. In my personal order of preference:

1. Use a more-specific selector. In this particular case, `click .edit-element:first` would probably do the trick, since the edit button comes before the child list's edit button.
2. Instead of using the Backbone `events` collection, bind directly to the element you're interested in. So before you render the child lists, do something like `this.$(".edit-element").click(_.bind(myClickHandler, this))`.
3. Put code inside the handler function to look at what element was clicked, and see if it's the one you're interested in. The code for this would be a little fiddly, and I don't think this is a particularly good solution, so no sample code. :)